# Synchronous message from localstorage lost in IE11

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11

I have a requirement which need to share messages from websocket among cross-domain tabs. So I set an iframe in each tab which listens localstorage event. When master tab receives a websocket message, set the message into localstorage and then other tabs or called slave tabs will get the localstorage event to do some reaction in page. It works well in chrome, but I encountered a problem in Edge and IE11. For some reason, I hope to save all the messages, so the key of these messages are like '__message_[random UUID]'. In edge and IE11, slave tabs can get the event and message key, but the message value is usually null.

Here is the code in iframe.

```
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        }
        if(e.data.type === 'ws-message') {
            var messageId_ = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
                v = c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
                return v.toString(16);
            });
            localstorage.setItem('__message_'+messageId_ , JSON.stringify({topic: e.data.topic, message: e.data.message}));
        }
    })
```

and where listen the event:

```
    window.addEventListener("storage", function(e){
        if(e.key.indexOf('__message_') === 0 && e.newValue !== null && __node_id__ !== __master_tab__){
            window.parent.postMessage({type: 'ws-message', message: JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem(e.key))}, '*');
        }
    })
```

Here I can get the `e.key`, but the `localstorage.getItem(e.key)` will be null.
At first I guess therer is some delay but when I set timeout in listen event, nothing changed.
PS: Websocket message receiving density is higher, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: I try to find some information regarding the issue and it looks like IE and Edge browsers has this issue. Ref: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110656/ At present I did not got any work around for the issue. I will again try to provide feedback to Microsoft regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you for your comment. I just found a wired thing. If I abandon the uuid for each message which means all the messages share the same key `__message_` and every time a new message comes in, I will change the value instead of saving it as a new one, then it works well. So I guess is the large amount of messages causing the problem mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I just find some clues. When I abandon the uuid for each message which means all the messages share the same key `__message_` and every time a new message comes in, I will change the value instead of saving it as a new one, then it works well. So I guess is the large amount of messages causing the problem mentioned above.